# What's the best way to delete object member and not have undefined left behind

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

What's the best way to delete object member and not have undefined left behind
as in

```
var o = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
delete o['a']
```

for a for loop over o will get us an undefined member.
I already have lodash running but `_.unset` doesn't seem to do the trick

thanks,

Sean.

Comment: `delete` doesn't leave anything behind, it deletes

Comment: @adeneo: That's the *perfect* way to phrase it. Nice one.

Answer (score 6):

`delete` is the way. [As adeneo said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320355/whats-the-best-way-to-delete-object-member-and-not-have-undefined-left-behind/40320383#comment67896534_40320355), `delete` doesn't leave anything behind. Once you `delete o.a`, `o` doesn't have the `a` property *at all*.<sup>1</sup> The only reason you'd see `undefined` would be if you asked for the property anyway, because asking for the value of a non-existent property on an object gives you back `undefined.`

> for a for loop over o will get us an undefined membe

Not any loop that works on the basis of `o`'s actual properties. For instance, not this one:

```js
var o = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   c: 3
}
delete o.a; // delete o['a']; also works
for (var name in o) {
  console.log(name + ": " + o[name]);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, it's possible to create a property that can't be deleted (by making the property non-configurable), but normal properties can be deleted. Here's how you'd create a non-configurable property:

```js
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, "a", {
    value: 42,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true
});
console.log(o.a); // 42
delete o.a;
console.log(o.a); // still 42
```

By not including `configurable: true`, we made the property non-configurable.

If you use strict mode, attempts to delete a non-configurable property are errors:

```js
"use strict";
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, "a", {
    value: 42,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true
});
console.log(o.a); // 42
delete o.a;       // throws error
console.log(o.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to get a property which does not exists, you get `undefined`. If you don't want that define a method that throws.

```
Object.defineProperty(o, 'a', {
  get: () => { throw Error("You can't access this property"); }
});
```

```js
var o = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
Object.defineProperty(o, 'a', {
  get: () => { throw Error("You can't access this property"); }
});
o.a; // Error: You can't access this property
```

You might also be interested in proxy objects:

```
var o = new Proxy(obj, {
  get: function(target, property, receiver) {
    if (property in target) return Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
    throw Error("The property does not exist");
  }
});
```

```js
var o = new Proxy({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}, {
  get: function(target, property, receiver) {
    if (property in target) return Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
    throw Error("The property does not exist");
  }
});
console.log(o.a); // 1
delete o.a;
console.log(o.a); // Error: The property does not exist
```